# Slow/no WIFI from main router after adding AP

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point

I have two TP-Link archer A6 routers. R1 as the main DHCP server connected to the modem. R2 is in AP mode wired to R1. Both routers have the same SSID so I can reconnect as I move around.

On my android: When I initially connect to R1, speed is good. As I move, I connect to R2 seamlessly and the speed is good. When I move back and reconnect to R1, the speed drops to zero as if it's not connected. I show full wifi bars.

As a test. I changed the SSID of R1, and the connection stays solid. I had also used this router in another application without problems, so I think the router is fine.

Is this a router problem or an Android problem? I have two TP-link extenders that can be hardwired and used as APs. I want to wire them to R2 so I have 3 APs in the house, 4, if I can get R1 working correctly. If I can't figure out R1, I would shut wifi off and just use R2 and the two extenders/APs.

Thanks for you help.
DAVE

Comment: Try reproducing the problem, and then send a broadcast or multicast ping from the device experiencing the problem. Of that clears up the problem, then you have a buggy router that isn't updating all of its bridge tables when clients roam.